# Index Directory Not Appearing

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, hibernate-search

When I create and persist several `@Indexed` objects using a `FullTextEntityManager` the index is created (and I can verify it by executing a hibernate search query using the `QueryBuilder`) the index is nowhere to be found. I've run filesystem searches trying to locate it, but nothing comes up. I only discovered it because I'm learning hibernate search and was trying to use Luke.

Update:
I'm using Hibernate Search 5.2.0 Final

persistence.xml:

```
<!--Hibernate Search Properties-->
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/Lucene/Indexes"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, I was missing a `.` before the file path. it should be `./Lucene/Indexes`

Comment: Hi @sarah-szabo could you mark your answer correct please, so it doesn't show up in my daily attempts to help Hibernate Search users ;)

Comment: @Sanne Sorry, my bad.